# EF6 - Insert multiple entities and update last

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm working with EF6 and I need to insert 2 entities and after update the last with some data of first.
This is an example:

```
var entity1 = new EntityT1();
setData(entity1);

var entity2 = new EntityT2();
setData(entity2);

ctx.Set<EntityT1>.Add(entity1);
ctx.Set<EntityT2>.Add(entity2);
ctx.SaveChanges();

//this is the result I would like
entity2.Prop1 = entity1.IdFromDb;
```

Can I make this in one step?
or...
I need to make two SaveChanges?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make this in one step? or... I need to make two SaveChanges? thanks

You will need to do it in two `SaveChanges`. There is nothing that ensures you that `entity 1` will be saved before `entity 2` (unless they have some dependency) since the order you add your entity in the ChangeTracker doesn't matter.

If there is a relation between `EntityT1` and `EntityT2`, I suggest you to use navigation property if that's the key but I don't think this is the scenario you are looking for.